# executeQueryAsync synchronously in each loop for sharepoint javascript model

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-clientobject

I am performing looping in javascript for sharepoint. I want it to perform synchronously, means only after first data execution is done it should start with second. If first data execution is completed (whether it success or fail) then only it should start with second in each loop.

```
$.each(selectedSiteCollections, function (index, value) {

                 act.SharePoint.SharePointAppProgress.addStatusRow(act.Resources.StatusInfo.applyFolderNavigation, "applyFolderNavigationId");
                 var siteUrl = value;//_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + "/" + projectUrl;
                 var  clientContext = act.SharePoint.SharePointAppCommon.getClientContext(siteUrl);
                 var newWebsite = clientContext.get_web();

                 var pageUrl = siteUrl + "/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx";
                 var homePageUrl = siteUrl + "/Pages/Home.aspx";

                 var jsLinkUrl = '~siteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/FolderNavigation.js'; //<-- specify JSLink url

                 var page = newWebsite.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(pageUrl);
                 var homePage = newWebsite.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(homePageUrl);



                 var wpm = page.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
                 var collWebPart = wpm.get_webParts();

                 var wpmHome = homePage.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
                 var collWebPartHome = wpmHome.get_webParts();

                 clientContext.load(homePage);
                 clientContext.load(collWebPart, 'Include(WebPart.Properties)');
                 clientContext.load(collWebPartHome, 'Include(WebPart.Properties)');

                 clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                     if (homePage.get_checkOutType() != SP.CheckOutType.online) {
                         homePage.checkOut();
                     }
                     var webPartDef = null;
                     for (var x = 0; x < collWebPart.get_count() && !webPartDef; x++) {
                         var temp = collWebPart.get_item(x);

                         webPartDef = temp;

                     }
                     if (webPartDef != null) {
                         var webpart = webPartDef.get_webPart();


                         var properties = webpart.get_properties();

                         properties.set_item('JSLink', jsLinkUrl);
                         webPartDef.saveWebPartChanges();
                     }


                     var webPartDefHome = null;
                     for (var x = 0; x < collWebPartHome.get_count() && !webPartDefHome; x++) {
                         var temp = collWebPartHome.get_item(x);

                         webPartDefHome = temp;

                     }
                     if (webPartDefHome != null) {
                         var webpart = webPartDefHome.get_webPart();


                         var properties = webpart.get_properties();

                         properties.set_item('JSLink', jsLinkUrl);
                         webPartDefHome.saveWebPartChanges();
                     }


                     homePage.checkIn("ACT Update webpart", SP.CheckinType.majorCheckIn);
                     homePage.publish("ACT Update webpart");
                     clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {

                         act.SharePoint.SharePointAppProgress.updateStatusRow(true, "applyFolderNavigationId");

                     }, function (sender, args) { executeAsyncFailed(sender, args, "applyFolderNavigationId"); });
                 }, function (sender, args) { executeAsyncFailed(sender, args, "applyFolderNavigationId"); });

             });
```

Comment: I think you will get more help at sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did that using custom looping logic :)

```
  var loop = function (i) {
                     enableFolderNavigation(selectedSiteCollections[i], i, function () {
                         if (++i < selectedSiteCollections.length) {
                             loop(i);
                         } else {
                             act.SharePoint.SharePointAppProgress.completed(true, "Completed");
                         }
                     });
                 };
                 loop(0);
```

and the function which contains async calls

```
  enableFolderNavigation = function (item, index, successFolderNavigation) {
           var siteUrl = item.link;//_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + "/" + projectUrl;
           var title = item.title;

           act.SharePoint.SharePointAppProgress.addStatusRow(act.Resources.StatusInfo.applyFolderNavigation + " :" + title, "applyFolderNavigationId" + index);

           var clientContext = act.SharePoint.SharePointAppCommon.getClientContext(siteUrl);
           var newWebsite = clientContext.get_web();

           var pageUrl = siteUrl + "/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx";
           var homePageUrl = siteUrl + "/Pages/Home.aspx";

           var jsLinkUrl = '~siteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/FolderNavigation.js'; //<-- specify JSLink url

           var page = newWebsite.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(pageUrl);
           var homePage = newWebsite.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(homePageUrl);



           var wpm = page.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
           var collWebPart = wpm.get_webParts();

           var wpmHome = homePage.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
           var collWebPartHome = wpmHome.get_webParts();

           clientContext.load(homePage);
           clientContext.load(collWebPart, 'Include(WebPart.Properties)');
           clientContext.load(collWebPartHome, 'Include(WebPart.Properties)');

           clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
              // if (homePage.get_checkOutType() != SP.CheckOutType.online) {
                   homePage.checkOut();
              // }
               var webPartDef = null;
               for (var x = 0; x < collWebPart.get_count() && !webPartDef; x++) {
                   var temp = collWebPart.get_item(x);

                   webPartDef = temp;

               }
               if (webPartDef != null) {
                   var webpart = webPartDef.get_webPart();


                   var properties = webpart.get_properties();

                   properties.set_item('JSLink', jsLinkUrl);
                   webPartDef.saveWebPartChanges();
               }


               var webPartDefHome = null;
               for (var x = 0; x < collWebPartHome.get_count() && !webPartDefHome; x++) {
                   var temp = collWebPartHome.get_item(x);

                   webPartDefHome = temp;

               }
               if (webPartDefHome != null) {
                   var webpart = webPartDefHome.get_webPart();


                   var properties = webpart.get_properties();

                   properties.set_item('JSLink', jsLinkUrl);
                   webPartDefHome.saveWebPartChanges();
               }


               homePage.checkIn("ACT Update webpart", SP.CheckinType.majorCheckIn);
               homePage.publish("ACT Update webpart");

               clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {

                   act.SharePoint.SharePointAppProgress.updateStatusRow(true, "applyFolderNavigationId" + index);
                   successFolderNavigation();
               }, function (sender, args) { executeAsyncFailed(sender, args, "applyFolderNavigationId" + index); successFolderNavigation(); });
           }, function (sender, args) { executeAsyncFailed(sender, args, "applyFolderNavigationId" + index); successFolderNavigation(); });

       },
```

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to run a synchronous foreach loop that contains asynchronous calls (`executeQueryAsync()`). Any logic dependent on the completion of an asynchronous call needs to be triggered by the asynchronous callback functions that indicate when the function has finished executing (and whether it failed or succeeded).

A viable approach would be to create a function that processes a *single* site. Use variables at a higher scope to track the collection of sites and the current index inside that collection. In the onSuccess and onFailure callbacks of your `executeQueryAsync()` call, increment the index and invoke the function to process the next site in the collection.